# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline with multiple sources with the same branch name

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have 3 interdependent micro service apps that I want to have builds/tests/deployments triggered for in Jenkins. My desired strategy is to use a single multibranch pipeline with multiple sources (one per micro service) that starts a pipeline every time there's a commit to their respective git repository.

Since the services are interdependent (functionality-wise, not build-wise), my over-simplified ideal output/layout would look something like:

`My_Product (multibranch pipeline)
 \- sprint-55
     |- micro_service_1_97dd2ae0 (pipeline)
     |- micro_service_2_8199aabb (pipeline)
     \- micro_service_3_9900ccff (pipeline)`

The problem I am running into with this approach is that our "main line" branches are named after the current sprint. So, as an example, micro_service_1 has a "sprint-55" branch as does micro_service_2 and micro_service_3. With the multibranch pipeline only the first micro service with a commit gets created. The remaining commits generate the following error:

`Error creating sprint-55 from source #2 as source #1 owns the branch name`

Is there a way to support what I want to do? I am open to other Jenkins-based options. I'd rather not have a multibranch pipeline for each micro service, but I can do that if it's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. I didn't find a way to run this setup under a single multibranch pipeline. So my solution was to create **multiple** multibranch pipelines.
In your case that would be one multibranch pipeline per each microservice.

That makes the pipelines independent from each other and makes it possible to use same branch names in different repos.